# Gulp get all matched files in a variable as array of strings

Tags: javascript, gulp

Using gulp I would like to have all matched files from `gulp.src()` in a variable.
I don't want to move files to `dist` I just want retrieve pattern matched files in a variable.
Something like this:

```
var files = gulp.src(['build/**/*.js', 'build/**/*.css']).pipe(<maybe-some-plugin-here>);
```

Where variable `files` would be an array of matched files.

I have tried using `gulp-filenames` but it doesn't work, just returns empty array.

Is there a, preferably simple, way to do accomplish this?

Comment: What's the goal behind this?

Comment: I want to make "clean" task where I would delete all files from "dist" folder but only those that are matched in "build" folder. I only want to delete files in "dist" (and some folders too), not in "build". So I thought that I need list of files for that do feed it to `del` plugin.